# Best practices for webapi data manipulation

Tags: magento2, webapi

I am building a custom subscription module. I have exposed a number of APIs for the frontend to consume.

I have the API hooked into standard repository endpoints:

```
public function getList(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria);
public function get(int $subId);
```

These all work fine, however, I want to 'expand' on these endpoints

I want to limit the results of `getList()` so it only returns the results belonging to the logged-in customer. At the moment I have just added an extra method to the repository `getCustomerList()` which adds an extra constraint on the search in a repository method.

Whilst this works, the repository doesn't feel like the right place for this additional 'authentication' logic.

Is there a better way to deal with this kind of thing? I read that the web API should always point to either a repository interface or a management interface. So how would an extra layer of logic on top of the repository fit in?

Comment: You mean that getList() method should return data when there is customer token in request header?